# How to return an error from `deserialize`?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

When implementing `Deserialize`, how to return an error?

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Response {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de> {
        ... // Which error to return here?
    }
}
```

Here every error must be convertible to `D::Error`, but `D::Error` maybe any whatsoever type. So, I cannot create a type convertible to `D::Error`.

How to deal with this situation? I am almost sure there is some way to create a deserializer that can return an error, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `D::Error` is required to implement [`serde::de::Error`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.152/serde/de/trait.Error.html) you can just use [`Error::custom`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.152/serde/de/trait.Error.html#tymethod.custom) or any of it's more specific constructors:

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Response {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de> {
        Err(<D::Error as serde::de::Error>::custom("your type imlementing `Display`"))
    }
}
```